# generate-migrations-diff failing with Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I am trying to generate a migration script using Doctrine with Zend Framework.  I am getting the following:

```
$ php doctrine.php generate-migrations-diff
$ PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Avo_Model_AccessType in 
$ tmp/fromprfx_doctrine_tmp_dirs/AccessType.php on line 16
```

I can successfully build the models form the yaml file.  I am using Zend Framework 1.10.5 and Doctrine 1.2.2  I think the issue might be with the autoloader and the fact that Zend Autoloads the classes that doctrine is trying to re-create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same error today. The problem was that in bootstrap I preloaded all models with

```
Doctrine_Core::loadModels($options['models_path']);
```

So, I just removed that line and it helped.